# Cygwin Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.surface.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass

Tags: java, cygwin, stanford-nlp

[image]

Hi,

I am trying to run the SPIED viz master demo of the Stanford Library that helps train the model on our own language tags. I am running this on Windows 7 with Cygwin. According to the documentation I got the setupWithCoreNLP.sh to work which put all the required jar files and other dependencies in the right folds and path. Now when I run demo.sh I get the main class not found error. I corrected the home path in the demo.sh file but I am not sure what else to fix to make this demo work. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you are running `java for windows` from `cygwin`, you have to change the paths or use `cygpath` command, since `java for windows` would not understand cygwin paths. Example: `java -cp $(cygpath -wp cygwin_path/file1.jar:cygwin_path/file2.jar) MainClass`. Post the script and java version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Albert. I am not using any script just following the step by step process given on the Stanford nlp website for pattern learning (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/patternslearning.shtml). I did change the HOME to HOME= C:\Users\k.shwetika\Desktop\NLP\SPIED-viz-master\SPIED-viz-master. Do I need to change this to cygpath? I am using Java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems using java for windows under `cygwin`:

- java for windows use `;` as jar separator (`:` is used for drives), while java for POSIX systems use `:`
- java for windows does not understand cygwin pathnames, like `/cygwin/c/Users/...`.   Please, take a look at [this article](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html), which explains how to handle cygwin POSIX pathnames while using windows programs, like `java`. [This one](http://www.horstmann.com/articles/cygwin-tips.html) can also be useful, although is more general.

In your case, I'd do something like:

```
java -cp $(cygpath -wp ./stanford-corenlp-3.5.1.jar:./stanford-corenlp-3.5.1-models.jar:./javax.json.jar:./joda-time.jar:./jollyday.jar) edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass -props patterns/example.properties
```

You'll have to change jars paths according to the appropiate directory.
I mean, if `stanford-corenlp-3.5.1.jar` is located in `C:\Users\k.shwetika\Desktop\NLP\SPIED-viz-master\SPIED-viz-master`, then change `./stanford-corenlp-3.5.1.jar` to 
`/cygdrive/c/Users/k.shwetika/Desktop/NLP/SPIED-viz-master/SPIED-viz-master/stanford-corenlp-3.5.1.jar`.

The same for the other jars.

Lastly, I assume `edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass` is within any of these jars.

**UPDATE**

I think, instead of using `cygpath` command to convert POSIX pathnames to windows pathnames, you can also use windows pathnames escaping jar separator `;` (ie: `\;`), but I not completely sure.

For example

```
java -cp win_path\jar1.jar\;...\;win_path\jarN.jar MainClass
```

Hope this helps!